# na.omit or complete case doesn't seem to eliminate the na values in histology column

Tags: r

my code for eliminating the rows containing NA values in histology column.

```
# package to read the excel file 
require(readxl)
dataset <- read_excel("All_Covariates_2008_08_21.xlsx")
# removing NA values
new_data <- dataset[complete.cases(dataset),]
#new_data <- na.omit(dataset)
attach(new_data)
```

I tried the above code (tried both complete.cases and na.omit)but somehow I still ended up with a single na value in histology.

Comment: Is it an actual `NA` or a string `"NA"`? We can not tell as you haven't provided a proper, reproducible example.

Comment: It is mentioned as NA in a column HISTOLOGY which otherwise has numeric values from 1 to 4.

Comment: Yes, but is it an actual `NA`? E.g. does `which(is.na(dataset$Histology))` return an index?

Comment: it returns integer(0). So, ill have to search it as string and eliminate. right ?

Comment: Yep, or replace `"NA"` with `NA` first, then use your original code.

Comment: Thanks ! got it now:)